# Accessing /var/log files from php

Tags: php, root, syslog

I want to use PHP to show some syslog info on a web page to remote monitor my home linux box.
I.e. some stuff filtered with grep out of /var/log/daemon.log

```
<?php
  $output = `grep ddclient /var/log/daemon.log`;
  echo "<pre>$output</pre>";
?>
```

Now the file /var/log/daemon.log is owned by root and the PHP user (www-data) has no access.
So obviously the above returns empty.

What's the solution?

Thanks,
Gert

Answer (score 2):

This is a variant of Puggan Se's setuid solution, but a bit better IMHO.

Create a `grep_ddclient.sh` shell script, containing:

```
#!/bin/sh
grep ddclient /var/log/daemon.log
```

Then add the following to `/etc/sudoers`:

```
apache ALL=NOPASSWD: /path/to/grep_ddclient.sh
```

Then run `sudo /path/to/grep_ddclient.sh` from PHP

Answer (score 1):

Alt 1:
  change read access of the file /var/log/daemon.log so apache can read it.

Alt 2:
  put `grep ddclient /var/log/daemon.log` in a shell file, and then activate the SETUID flag on it, and give apache the right to execute it

```
chown root:apache grep_ddclient.sh
chmod 550 grep_ddclient.sh
chmod +s grep_ddclient.sh
```

and then run grep_ddclient.sh from php